# pyspark ibmdpy giving ValueError: ('ordinal must be >= 1

Tags: apache-spark, ibm-cloud, dashdb

I am loading data from netezza into a dataframe and then trying to write to dashdb.  I am using ibmdpy to try to load the data into dashdb on bluemix.  Ibmdpy requires a pandas dataframe so I convert the spark dataframe to pandas to load into dashdb.

```
all_disputes_df = sqlContext.read.format('jdbc').options(url='jdbc:netezza://pda1-wall.pok.ibm.com:5480/BACC_PRD_ISCNZ_GAPNZ', user=user, password=password, dbtable='METRICS.AR_EM_D2_02_AGG', driver='org.netezza.Driver').load()
from ibmdbpy import IdaDataBase
idadb = IdaDataBase(dsn='BLUDB', uid='dash107474', pwd='k5TY24AbzFjE')
print("current_schema is %s" % idadb.current_schema)
print("tables %s" % idadb.show_tables())
idadb.as_idadataframe(all_disputes_df.toPandas(), "all_disputes")
```

I am getting the following traceback.

---

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-63dde713c67b> in <module>()
----> 1 idadb.as_idadataframe(all_disputes_df.toPandas(), "all_disputes")

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in toPandas(self)
1379         """
1380         import pandas as pd
-> 1381         return pd.DataFrame.from_records(self.collect(), columns=self.columns)
1382 
1383     ##########################################################################################

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/dataframe.pyc in collect(self)
279         with SCCallSiteSync(self._sc) as css:
280             port = self._jdf.collectToPython()
--> 281         return list(_load_from_socket(port, BatchedSerializer(PickleSerializer())))
282 
283     @ignore_unicode_prefix

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/rdd.pyc in _load_from_socket(port, serializer)
140     try:
141         rf = sock.makefile("rb", 65536)
--> 142         for item in serializer.load_stream(rf):
143             yield item
144     finally:

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.pyc in load_stream(self, stream)
137         while True:
138             try:
--> 139                 yield self._read_with_length(stream)
140             except EOFError:
141                 return

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.pyc in _read_with_length(self, stream)
162         if len(obj) < length:
163             raise EOFError
--> 164         return self.loads(obj)
165 
166     def dumps(self, obj):

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/serializers.pyc in loads(self, obj, encoding)
420     else:
421         def loads(self, obj, encoding=None):
--> 422             return pickle.loads(obj)
423 
424 

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in <lambda>(*a)
1157 # This is used to unpickle a Row from JVM
1158 def _create_row_inbound_converter(dataType):
-> 1159     return lambda *a: dataType.fromInternal(a)
1160 
1161 

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in fromInternal(self, obj)
563             return obj
564         if self._needSerializeAnyField:
--> 565             values = [f.fromInternal(v) for f, v in zip(self.fields, obj)]
566         else:
567             values = obj

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in fromInternal(self, obj)
436 
437     def fromInternal(self, obj):
--> 438         return self.dataType.fromInternal(obj)
439 
440 

/home/brente/spark/spark-1.6.1-bin-hadoop2.6/python/pyspark/sql/types.pyc in fromInternal(self, v)
174     def fromInternal(self, v):
175         if v is not None:
--> 176             return datetime.date.fromordinal(v + self.EPOCH_ORDINAL)
177 
178 
ValueError: ('ordinal must be >= 1', <function <lambda> at 0x7f97c0be76e0>, (u'788', u'10', u'00620000  ', u'0129101548  ', 1, u'000028628   ', 16520, Decimal('2124.76'), Decimal('2124.76'), 16525, 16525, u'000611099
```

Any ideas on what the problem is?

Answer (score 0):

Reading your data from Netezza into dataframes fails. Everything beyond that is speculation from my side:

1. Could there be invalid data stored in Netezza, that throws off the deserialization into dataframes?
2. Maybe try some other queries, to make sure that there is no connectivity problem, no typo in the database name, things like that.

Comment: The data in netezza is probably malformed.  I don't think I can do anything about it though.  What I am trying to accomplish is to move the data from netezza into dashdb.  some of the netezza data fields are comments where there are probably new-line characters and maybe even people cutting and pasting emails, ...  I already know the spark-netezza way of reading the data cannot handle the newlines, that is why I am using the jdbc method to read.  I have successfully read the data before using the jdbc method.

Comment: You could try to run your own sanitizing logic over the dataframe before converting it to a Pandas dataframe. But I lack practice in this area, so I cannot give you more specific guidance.